# Increase primefaces inputTextArea rows on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I would like a primefaces inputTextarea that when focused will change its rows="1" property to rows="10."

I try this but it doesn't work:

```
 <p:inputTextarea rows="1" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.rows =
 '1';" onfocus="this.rows ='50'"/>
```

With a h:inputTextArea it's work but I prefer the primefaces inputTextArea because of autoresize.

May I miss something?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your attributes and logic are fine with the framework then are you sure that `this.value` is empty string?
Try `if(!this.value)` than you might continue your search if no success.
If success you'll have to make more accurate boolean statement.

Comment: <p:inputTextarea rows="1" onfocus="this.rows ='50'"/> doesn't increase the number of rows

Comment: maybe number of rows is defined  `onRender` only and you can't do it dynamically on client using this approach

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works - this solution is not based on rows but on changing the height and also works with ajax updates (when html content got updated in the page or was lazy loaded)

```
$(document).on("focus", "textarea.expand", function() {
     $(this).animate({ height: "12em" }, 500); 
});

$(document).on("blur", "textarea.expand", function() {
     $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500); 
});
```

JSF part:

`<h:inputTextarea id="testDescriptionTextBox" 
    styleClass="expand" value="#{tributeToBlagusC.testDescription}" 
    rows="4" cols="120" autoResize="false"/>`

Comment: Please re-read the question. OP states it works for an `h:inputText` and wants a solution for a `p:inputText`